# Java dragging sprite starts redraws from the beginning

Tags: java, java-2d

when I drag my sprite, instead of dragging it from the same position, it will re-locate the sprite with the currently clicked X, Y position. this is because the sprite will draw right away on the clicked position.

```
    if (super.mouseDragging && System.currentTimeMillis() - super.mouseTimer >= 200) {
        PosX = super.mouseX;
        PosY = super.mouseY;
    }
```

`PosX/PosY` = the position of the sprite.

How do I exactly make it so when you click on the sprite, it won't relocate it with the new X,Y and just process the dragging smoothly? I thought of adding offsets off the current position but I am not sure how exactly.

Is there a proper way of doing this?

Example of good dragging:

http://scratch.mit.edu/projects/2098337/

```
        grabbedX = super.mouseX - PosX;
        grabbedY = super.mouseY - PosY;
        PosX = super.mouseX - grabbedX;
        PosY = super.mouseY - grabbedY;

X: -108 Y: -82
X: 108 Y: 83
X: -108 Y: -83
X: 108 Y: 84
X: -108 Y: -84
X: 107 Y: 85
X: -107 Y: -85
X: 107 Y: 85
X: -107 Y: -85
X: 107 Y: 85
X: -107 Y: -85


    if (x >= client.PosX && x <= client.PosX + 229 
            && y >= client.PosY && y <= client.PosY + 70) {
        this.mouseDragging = true;
        this.mouseTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("yes");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("no");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it.  Calculate the offset between the object origin and the clicked position, then maintain the offset as you set the position during dragging.  If you don't do this, you'll see that initial "jump" as it is sets the object's origin at the clicked mouse position (that is unless you happen to grab the object at its origin).

I normally do something like this when the object is "grabbed".  This is calculated once, say for example in your `mousePressed()` method:

```
Point origin = thing.getPosition();
scene.grabbedOffsetX = (mousePos.x - origin.x);
scene.grabbedOffsetY = (mousePos.y - origin.y);
```

Then when you redraw during the dragging operation you factor in the previously calculated offset.  The offset remains constant throughout the dragging operation.  This would be for example in your `mouseDragged()` method:

```
thing.setPosition(mousePos.x - grabbedOffsetX, mousePos.y - grabbedOffsetY);
repaint();
```

Comment: I assume if the start X is bigger than dragX, then do StartX - dragX right & same for Y, right?

Comment: This just doesn't move my sprite, am i doing anything wrong? view my edit

Comment: @user3123545 There's a lot of code I'm not seeing, so it's hard to day.  The only thing you changed was adding an offset to how you calculated the position -- so nothing should have broken.  Print out the values of offsets to make sure they make sense.  They should be reasonable values and less in magnitude than the size of the sprite.

Comment: Added the dewbugging vaues of offsets above.

Comment: its probaby my detecting if mouse is touching the sprite, see my edit i've added the code. when i drag my sprite flashes, i see 2 copies of the sprite, one copy is correct, second copy is on the very right, and when i place the sprite, the sprite will be the second copy, on the right.

Comment: @user3123545 Something is definitely off with those values.  I updated my answer again for clarity.  Be sure you are only calculating the offset once.  The offset values should not change during the dragging process.

Comment: This did not work, but I tried including width and height, so grabbedX = (mouseX - width) - posX and so on for Y, but now it's the opposite, if I drag from left, it will drag from right, know what I mean?

Comment: Fixed! you needed to do origin.x - mousePosX instead ;) thank you~!